# How to make PR from fork with custom Github workflows without including changes to `.github/workflows`

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to write a Github workflow that runs in a fork of `Bioconda-Recipes`. The workflow should:

1. Check if there is a new release for a specific packege (say `Nextclade`)
2. If that's the case, in the `Nextclade` recipe, update the `version` and `sha` checksum in the recipe
3. Open a new PR that would change *only* the `Nextclade` recipe, I *do not* want my fork's `.github` directory changes to be included in the PR

I'm conceptually stuck on part 3. How do I open a PR that excludes/ignores certain changes in the fork with respect to upstream?

Do I need to pull/checkout/reset the upstream version of the `.github` folder? What's the easiest way to solve this?

Comment: A PR is from a branch, so _any_ changes in that branch will be included. You could create a new branch for the PR, then cherry pick changes _outside_ `.github/` over to it, for example.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, so this is doable with some git-fu. Do you know if there exist any pre-configured actions for something like that? Or is my need to rare?